# Bootstrap Datepicker open on second click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have scenario where I add calendar dynamically and on click I get id of specific calendar and initialize but it open on second click. Below is my code

```
$(document).on('click', '.cal', function () {

        $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            var providerid = $(this).attr('providerid');
            var facilityid = $(this).attr('facilityid');
            var resourceid = $(this).attr('resourceid');
            var clickid = $(this).attr('dateid');
            var inputDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date($('#' + $(this).attr('id')).datepicker('getDate')));
            $('#facility' + $.trim(facilityid) + ' #' + $.trim($(this).attr('dateid')) + ' span').html(inputDate);

            Scheduling_MuliView.BackDate(clickid, providerid, resourceid, facilityid, 0);

            $(this).datepicker('hide');

        });
    });
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: how exactly you add the calendar trigger `.cal` elements?

Comment: .cal is created dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind a click event on class `.cal` you just directly assign it to that element.

```
$( ".cal" ).datepicker(
   format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
   todayHighlight: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the `datepicker` function means **init** it but not **open** the picker.

IN my opinion, the

```
$(this).attr('id')).datepicker ...
```

Would be called in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cal').datepicker ...
});
```

*Or somewhere as soon as you add the picker into the HTML.*

Comment: @user2689563 then please give me the code to create the cal. U need to add this line of `$(".cal")......` after it.